# Language not changed in android

Tags: android, localization

I have tried to change the language of to all my activity.But it does not change.I have tried initially for changing the language in single activity. what to do for changing the language at all activity.`

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setContentView(R.layout.language);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1) ;



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i= new Intent(LocalizationUpdaterActivity.this,HomePage.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        spinner.setPrompt("select language");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,languages);

/*        ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, languages);*/
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                switch (arg2) {

                    case 0:
                       Locale myLocale = new Locale("fa");
                        Resources res = getResources();
                        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
                        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
                        conf.locale = myLocale;
                        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
                        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(
                                getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration(),
                                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                        setContentView(R.layout.language);
                        Intent refresh = new Intent(LocalizationUpdaterActivity.this, LocalizationUpdaterActivity.class);
                        startActivity(refresh);
                        break;
                    default:
                        config.locale = Locale.TAIWAN;
                        break;
                }
                getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }


    private String[] languages = { "Inglese", "Italiano", "Francese" };
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
String language = "fr";
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

from [SDK documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale))

Comment: How to change the language in all activity@Veener

Comment: Is there any simple way to change language without using string values

Comment: What do you mean by all activity?  All activities in your app?

Answer (score 0):

you must change language on launch time.

create a class like this:

```
public class ApplicationBase extends Application
{

    public final String TAG = "ApplicationBase";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        yourChangeLangMethod();
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml insert this:

```
<application
    android:name = ".ApplicationBase"
    android:icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label = "@string/app_label"
    android:theme = "@style/AppTheme">
```